# out file with multiple criteria in python?

Tags: python

Given that the infile contains:

```
aaaaaaa"pic01.jpg"bbbwrtwbbbsize 110KB
aawerwefrewqa"pic02.jpg"bbbertebbbsize 100KB
atyrtyruraa"pic03.jpg"bbbwtrwtbbbsize 190KB
```

How to obtain the outfile as:

```
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

My code is:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        lines_set1 = line.split ('"')
        lines_set2 = line.split (' ')
        for item_set1 in lines_set1:
            for item_set2 in lines_set2:
                if item_set1.endswith ('.jpg'):
                    if item_set2.endswith ('KB'):
                            outfile.write (item_set1 + ' ' + item_set2 + '\n')
```

What is wrong with my code, please help!
The problem has been solved here:
[what is wrong in the code written inpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675812/what-is-wrong-in-the-code-written-inpython)

Comment: [Nothing is wrong with your code](http://ideone.com/f125S6)

Comment: @Eric the outfile is blank

Comment: Not in that link I posted it isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and `str.rsplit` here, your code seems to be an overkill for this simple task:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = 'aaaaaaa"pic01.jpg"bbbwrtwbbbsize 110KB\n'
>>> name = re.search(r'"(.*?)"', strs).group(1)
>>> size = strs.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
>>> name, size
('pic01.jpg', '110KB')
```

or

```
>>> name, size = re.search(r'"(.*?)".*?(\w+)$', strs).groups()
>>> name, size
('pic01.jpg', '110KB')
```

Now use string formatting:

```
>>> "{} {}\n".format(name, size) #write this to file
'pic01.jpg 110KB\n'
```

Comment: i want to write outfile.txt as in my question @Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: thanks but can not my code be corrected instead of using re? @Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: my question is about the use of multiple line.split  as in my code @Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: @leanne That makes your question a perfect example for [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Often you can solve string manipulation problems without regex as Python has an amazing string library. In your case, just calling `str.split` twice with different delimiters (quote and space) solves your issue

Demo

```
>>> st = """aaaaaaa"pic01.jpg"bbbwrtwbbbsize 110KB
aawerwefrewqa"pic02.jpg"bbbertebbbsize 100KB
atyrtyruraa"pic03.jpg"bbbwtrwtbbbsize 190KB"""
>>> def foo(st):
    #Split the string based on quotation mark
    _, fname, rest = st.split('"')
    #from the residual part split based on space
    #and select the last part
    rest = rest.split()[-1]
    #join and return fname and the residue
    return ' '.join([fname, rest])

>>> for e in st.splitlines():
    print foo(e)


pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex would be easier:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        m = re.search('"([^"]+)".*? (\d+.B)', line)
        if m:
            outfile.write(m.group(1) + ' ' + m.group(2) + '\n')
```