# what is wrong in the code written inpython

Tags: python, string, file

Given that the infile contains:

```
aaaaaaa"pic01.jpg"bbbwrtwbbbsize 110KB
aawerwefrewqa"pic02.jpg"bbbertebbbsize 100KB
atyrtyruraa"pic03.jpg"bbbwtrwtbbbsize 190KB
```

How to obtain the outfile as:

```
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

My code is:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        lines_set1 = line.split ('"')
        lines_set2 = line.split (' ')
        for item_set1 in lines_set1:
            for item_set2 in lines_set2:
                if item_set1.endswith ('.jpg'):
                    if item_set2.endswith ('KB'):
                            outfile.write (item_set1 + ' ' + item_set2 + '\n')
```

But the code produces blank file. What is wrong with it??

Comment: Why do you use nested for loops?

Comment: You should use regular expressions.

Comment: @Sebastian how is the correction?

Comment: Did you add print statements throughout your file to see what it was doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have only one major problem: `if item_set2.endswith ('KB')` check doesn't work since there is a new-line char at the end of each line. Replace it with (note `strip()` call):

```
if item_set2.strip().endswith('KB'):
```

Also, you don't need `+ '\n'` since `item_set2` already contains a new-line at the end:

```
outfile.write (item_set1 + ' ' + item_set2.strip())
```

FYI, you can use regex with saving groups to extract the data:

```
import re


with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        match = re.search(r'"(.*)"\w+\s(\w+)', line)
        outfile.write(' '.join(match.groups()) + "\n")
```

The contents of `outfile.txt` after running the code:

```
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

Comment: i want to solve the problem in the way i have written the code, rather than importing re @alecxe

Comment: @leanne ok, updated the answer, please check.

Comment: When you write "your code" are you referring to the question, or some other answer? Your answer would be better if you clarified.

Comment: @alecxe thanks. i did not understand why strip()call is required by item_set2 but not by item_set1

Comment: @leanne since `item_set2` items are at the end of lines.

Comment: @alecxe ok, i have accepted your answer

Comment: @leanne yeah, thanks for it. Someone just added -1 and it would be good to know why.

Comment: @alecxe I have gotten used to getting random -1s on answers. Mostly from people who don't understand it, sadly.  (E.g. in this case it could be from people who knee-jerk about regular expressions as if they're not one of the most useful search tools ever put into action.)

Answer (score 3):

A solution without the need to import `re`. The condition can be improved into a one-line condition.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        filename = line.strip().split('"')[1]
        size = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
        if filename.endswith('.jpg') and size.endswith('KB'):
            outfile.write('%s %s\n' % (filename, size))
```

Comment: `size = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]` is better.

Answer (score 2):

You should use regex, which will simplify your code. With something like:

```
import re
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        obj = re.match('.+"(.+\.jpg)".+\s(\d+KB)', line)
        if obj:
             outfile.write (obj.group(1) + ' ' + obj.group(2) + '\n')
```

outfile.txt returned by this script:

```
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

Comment: i want to solve the problem in the way i have written the code, rather than importing re @Maxime Lorant

Comment: You code is quite dirty. Why do you want to keep the nested loop solution?

Answer (score 2):

First, split the line at spaces and take the second item (in 0 based list, first item), This will give the size part.

Next, split the first item at " and take the second item. That will give the filename.

Check the online Demo, if you want to know how it splits.

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        Parts = line.split()
        outfile.write (Parts[0].split('"')[1] + " " + Parts[1] + "\n")
```

**Output:**

```
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```

**Online Demo:**

http://ideone.com/EOcuXL

Comment: i want to solve the problem in the way i have written the code, rather than importing re @thefourtheye

Comment: We dont use `re` now. Please check

Comment: You still have the `"bbbwrtwbbbsize` to remove from the first part.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Added a demo for you :)

Comment: I have used the `split()` method with the second argument at 1 too much these last weeks, that's why I got a little confused :-)

Comment: @MaximeLorant Thats okay. We all do that often :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
$ sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*size \(.*\)/\1 \2/' foo.txt
pic01.jpg 110KB
pic02.jpg 100KB
pic03.jpg 190KB
```